# What is the significance of feeding cows in hinduism

Tags: scripture, vedas, krishna, manuscripts, cows

Usually, it is said that feeding cows is equivalent to feeding many gods. Is this just a figurative speech or is the significance of feeding cows, mentioned anywhere in our scriptures?

Comment: If you see that all deities are present in cows it makes sense to say that by feeding cows deities can be pleased.

Comment: A related post -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9247/4732